# Error when trying to clone my Heroku app into my local machine

Tags: git, ubuntu, heroku, clone, heroku-cli

I'm running an app on heroku . But unfortunately very recently I lost my files on my hdd and now I'm trying to clone back my backend on my hard drive.

i tried to run the following from heroku cli to clone my app onto my local machine:

`heroku git:clone -a myAppName`

But i get this error:

`▸    ENOENT: spawn git ENOENT`

any idea what the problem is?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this means that git isn't found. You either need to install it or add it to your path environment variable

Comment: Thx Jeff . I do have git on my ubuntu, but I'll give it another try . But anyway I tried that same command on a windows and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:** Remove the `snap` version of `heroku` and install it via `apt-get`

```
$ sudo snap remove heroku
$ sudo add-apt-repository "deb https://cli-assets.heroku.com/branches/stable/apt ./"
$ curl -L https://cli-assets.heroku.com/apt/release.key | sudo apt-key add -
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install heroku
```